# scrollbar can not work well in different tabs of Tkinter notebook with python 2.7.10 on macos

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, ttk

I create a notebook frame with two tabs, and each tab has a Text component and a Scrollbar component.
but in this case the scrollbar can not work well.

the exceptions like this:

1. launch this script
2. select the 'tab 1', then I can drag it's scroll bar slider
3. select the 'tab 2', then I can drag it's scroll bar slider

**4. then, select 'tab 1' again, but I can not drag the scroll bar slider in 'tab 1' at this time.**

os:MacOS

version:the default python V2.7.10 on mac system

is there any body know how to solve this problem? and why?

```py
# coding=utf-8
from Tkinter import (Tk, Text, Scrollbar)
from Tkconstants import (END, RIGHT, X, Y, BOTH, YES)
import ttk

def add_tab_with_text(master,title):
    '''add a tab to ttk.Notebook, and add a Text with scrollbar to each tab'''
    mytab = ttk.Frame(master)
    master.add(mytab, text=title)

    # set Scrollbar
    scrollbar_v = Scrollbar(mytab)
    scrollbar_v.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    # set Text
    mytext = Text(mytab, width=40, height=40)
    mytext.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_v.set)
    mytext.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

    # Text insert message
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        mytext.insert(END, '%s line: %d.0\n' % (title,i))

    # Scrollbar add bind
    scrollbar_v.config(command=mytext.yview)

main_win = Tk()
main_win.title('Scrollbar test')
main_win.geometry('800x800')

nb = ttk.Notebook(main_win)
add_tab_with_text(nb,'tab 1') # create Tab 1
add_tab_with_text(nb,'tab 2') # create Tab 2

nb.pack(fill='both',side='top')
main_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me with python3 on OSX. Python 2.7 is very old, perhaps you should try upgrading.

Comment: No matter when we selected the 'tab 1' or 'tab 2', the scrollbar of the tab always can response with the MouseWheel normally!

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, Thanks for your help. The abnormal state is that it has the same phenomenon even with python3 to run it on my macbook. and it always can response with MouseWheel normally but with The right mouse button to drag the scroll bar slider! any more suggestion about this problem?

Comment: @auspark why are you trying to drag the scrollbar with the `right mouse button`? shouldn't you be doing that with `LMB`? or is that something different with MacBooks? 
and as Bryan said, your code works fine on his OSX, so it's either an issue with the OS or compatibility.

Comment: @ P S Solanki Thank you! Now I'm sure the script is fine. Maybe it's because of the OS or other issue. I will work on this and try to find the root cause! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been finished an test for this issue just now,
When I config pack side with different value,'right' or 'left', It will work well.

one scrollbar config pack side to 'right'

```py
crollbar_v.pack(side='right', fill=Y, expand=True)
```

another scrollbar config pack side to 'left'

```py
crollbar_v.pack(side='left', fill=Y, expand=True)
```

It's too strange!